# Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14 to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I try to parse format date `Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14` to dd/mm/yyyy

this  is my code

```
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
   System.out.println(formatter.parse(date_retour.toString()));
```

error `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14"`

help please

it is okay now

```
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);  
        SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");  
        Date date;
        date = formatter.parse(date_retour.toString());
        donnees [i][9]  =formatter2.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(operation2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: 30 March 2014 was a Sunday. Wonder why it says “Fri” in the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match the date format pattern with the input `String`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: yes i'm using the pattern format EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z but again java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 14"

Comment: The day of week and/or month name from your default `Locale` may not match those from your input String. Try with `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH)`

Comment: On a computer with an English-speaking locale this yields Mon Mar 30 00:00:00 CET 1970. It picks the default year, 1970, which is hardly what you intended, and also ignores the input day-of-week because you haven’t got a year in your format pattern (to match the 14 in the input). Also I suggest giving the `SimpleDateFormat` an explicit locale.

Comment: I agree that codeur, the original poster, should have posted his solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question. But solving that by leaving the edit unformatted and difficult to read? Should I rather move it to a new answer? (codeur was last seen on the site in 2014)